# wordpress adds <br/> tag after image uploaded

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm tryng to build a slide-show in my wordpress blog.I'm using [jqTransitions](http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/) plugin but I have an issue.

This plugin requires that you have a `div` (id=slide-show) with all of the images you want to show inside.

```
<script>
//SLIDE-SHOW GALLERY
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#slide-show').jqFancyTransitions();
});
</script>

//and images inside slide-show div
<div id="slide-show" >
    <img src="images/gallery/1.jpg" alt="RAN" title="My title">
    <img src="images/gallery/2.jpg" alt="AJISAI" title="Another title">
    <img src="images/gallery/3.jpg" alt="HIMAWARI" title="My title">                
</div>
```

Everything works perfectly outside of wordpress. The point is when I add the slide-show `div` in a wordpress page, it automatically adds a `<br />` after each image, so that she images are sliding not aligned!

[image]

How can I prevent wordpress to add `br` tag right after each image?

**SOLVED:**

WORDPRESS was actually considering the newline between each image tag as a br tag.Have to write evertyhting on the same line.

Comment: im working on my own theme but did not set anything like that..so ,if you think it's theme-dependent issue,I guess it's inheriting the default settings (wordpress 3.2.1)

Comment: anyway I tried with twentyeleven 1.1 and 1.2 and have the same issue

Comment: You could *try* wrapping `<li>` elements around each element and making a list (it's not really semantic, but it should stop WP from parsing it in this way and you'd have more readable mark-up. I imagine the plugin just cycles through each element; similar plugins take lists with no problems.

Comment: Since you figured out the solution to this issue, you should put it as answer to this question and accept it.  That way people in the future can easily see what the issue was (in case they run into the same thing) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORDPRESS was actually considering the newline between each image tag as a br tag.Have to write evertyhting on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove it with this code:

`jQuery('.zoomthumbnail-image').next('br').remove();`